# How to calculate the expected number of leaves in BST?

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures

Given **n (n > 1)** distinct numbers (**1, 2, 3, ..., n** for example) in random order, insert them to an empty BST successively. The expected number of its leaves is **(n + 1) / 3**.

I tried to use method of mathematical induction:
**f[n]** is the expected number of leaves in a BST build with n distinct numbers. What I thaught about is which place the nth number is interted to (it will be a leaf node). If its father node used not to be a leaf, then the number of leaves would increase by one. So I calculated the possibility of it being such a node: **(n / 3 + 1) / (2n / 3 + 1)** (equation set **n0 = n2 + 1**, **n0 + n1 + n2 = n** and **n0 = n / 3** where **ni** mean the number of node with **i** children helps to calculate the number of each kind of node) but it's obviously not **1 / 3** so **f[n + 1]** does not equal to **f[n] + 1 / 3**.

Could someone explain it? Thanks!

Comment: _"I tried to use method of mathematical induction but failed"_. Where did you fail? Add whatever approach/conclusion you were able to reach

Comment: Edit your question, add this info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is wrong, because it assumes some sort of "average" tree with exactly the right number of leaves.

Here's a valid proof. Maybe there's something shorter, but this looks right to me.

We want to prove by induction that the average number of leaves L[n] is 0 for n=0, 1 for n=1 and (n+1)/3 for n>1.

The base cases are easy to check: L[0] = 0, L[1] = 1, L[2] = 1.

Suppose (for induction) it's true for all tree sizes less than n. That is, L[m] = (m+1)/3 for all m<n.

If you're shuffling (1...n) and then inserting them into a BST, then the root of the tree is the first item in the permutation (call it k), there's (k-1) things off the left child, and (n-k) things off the right child. Each of those subtrees satisfies the induction hypothesis -- it's a BST formed by a random permutation of some set of distinct numbers. By linearity of expectation, and because each k=1..n is equally likely, L[n] = sum(L[k-1] + L[n-k], k=1..n)/n.

Now, L[n] = sum(L[k-1] + L[n-k], k=1..n)/n = ((L[0] + L[n-1]) + (L[1] + L[n-2]) + sum(L[k-1] + L[n-k], k=3..n-2) + (L[n-2] + L[1]) + (L[n-1] + L[0]))/n -- this is just separating out the k=1, 2, n-1 and n cases from the sum.

And L[0] + L[n-1] + L[1] + L[n-2] = n/3 + 1 + (n-1)/3 (by induction) = 2/3 + 2n/3

And sum(L[k-1] + L[n-k], k=3..n-2) = sum(k/3 + (n-k+1)/3, k=3..n-2) = (n+1)(n-4)/3 (by induction)

So the average number of leaves is (4/3 + 4n/3 + (n+1)(n-4)/3) / n = (n+1)/3.

Answer (score 2):

After inserting n nodes, we expect f(n) leaves.  Obviously we have f(1)=1.

Of the n+1 places that a new node could be inserted, we therefore expect that 2f(n) of those are under leaves.  We expect non-leaf nulls to number n+1-2f(n)

---

LEMMA: The probability of inserting into a leaf or non-leaf null is proportional to the expected number of leaves or non-leaves.

Let p(n,m) be the probability that you have m leaves after inserting n nodes.

The expected number of leaves is f(n) = sum_for_m=1_to_n(m * p(n,m))

If a tree has n nodes and m leaves, then the probability of inserting the next node under a leaf is 2m/(n+1).  The unconditional probability of inserting under a leaf is therefore:

sum_for_m=1_to_n(2m/(n+1) * p(n,m)) = 2f(n)/(n+1)

---

Inserting under a leaf will not change the number of leaves, but inserting under a non-leaf will increase the leaf count by one, so we have:

f(n+1) = f(n) + (n+1-2f(n))/(n+1)

or

f(n) = f(n-1) + (n-2f(n-1))/n = 1 + f(n-1) - 2f(n-1)/n

Now it's easy to prove by induction that (n+1)/3 works for all n.  If f(n-1) = n/3, then:

f(n) = 1 + n/3 - 2n/3n = (n+1)/3

Comment: I upvoted, but when you're considering where a new node can be inserted, I think you're switching between a concrete tree and the average case -- which isn't valid or at least I don't see that it's obvious. To see that your proof is actually right I had to imagine the n! different BSTs generated by possible orderings of the first n elements and convince myself that each possible leaf and non-leaf parent was equally likely given the n+1 values the new node can take. Maybe that's obvious to you, or maybe you had a different insight to validate the correctness of the insert step.

Comment: @PaulHankin, I'm not using any concrete trees. I'm turning the expectation f(n-1) into a probability 2f(n-1)/n. This is valid because computing either one from the distribution of leaf counts for case n-1 nodes is essentially the same integration.  I added a lemma for that